# Integrating browser upload to S3 with a private REST API

Tags: rest, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, jquery-file-upload

We have a private REST API for file uploads, which uses S3 for storage. The API conforms very closely to the RESTful design outlined [here](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2011/06/02/asynchronous-operations-in-rest/). Currently when a file is uploaded it is buffered initially to the server (on EC2), then sent on for storage in our S3 bucket. The API is consumed mainly by our internal web applications, but in order to handle large file uploads we want to make use of the [jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin, which, combined with an S3 `POST` form, allows for direct upload to S3 from the browser.

We wish to keep all our internal applications API-centric, to avoid a host of one-off, ad hoc solutions. I cannot see how to integrate this browser upload method with our current REST API endpoints, however. In general they work (as in the linked blog post) by returning a `202 Accepted` response once data has been sent successfully through them, with the Location header pointing to a queue resource which can be queried for status updates.

If no data is ever sent through the API itself, however, what is the right request-response pattern? What kind of RESTful solution (if there is one) is appropriate in this case?

Comment: before attempting to answer your question....

why do you want to handle the upload yourself rather than doing a direct s3 post?  allowing the direct s3 post is much easier to scale... you outsource scaling to amazon

Comment: @philswenson Many thanks. Leaving aside the fact, which I neglected to mention, that we might well eventually make our API public, I think the scaling issue is dealt with by our EC2 setup, consisting of an autoscaling group behind an elastic load balancer. But actually handling the upload myself is precisely _not_ what I want to do right now. I probably wasn't very clear... I'm trying to figure out the general REST architecture for an API involving a direct browser upload, because it certainly seems to break our current design.

Comment: @philswenson One way this might work is if an initial request is made to the API for an upload token (a uuid). Then the jquery uploader stores the data in S3 using the uuid as the key (this is how we store things at the moment, and the queue resource is also identified by it). When upload has completed the ajax 'done' callback performs another API request to inform the server, which returns `202 Accepted` and sets the Location header, as before.